# How to disable OR condition optimization in Postgres/Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a model called `A` with columns `col` and `col2`. The `col1` has an unique index. (I am using Postgres database.)

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  # id, col1, col2
end
```

Data:

```
id  col1   col2
==  ====   ====
1   2       3
2   3       4
```

Let us try to find the first row matching the given value in `col2` OR `col1`.

```
a = A.first(:conditions=> ["col2 = :id OR col1 = :id", {:id => 3}])
# select * from A where (col2 = 3 OR col1 = 3) LIMIT 1
```

The SQL above returns the row#2 rather than row#1. I suspect the query optimizer chooses to execute `col1 = 3` first as `col1` has an unique index.

How do I override this behavior? How do I instruct Postgres optimizer to use the existing order for the OR condition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't specify an explicit order then *first row* doesn't make any sense; the result set from a specific query at a specific moment in time will, of course, have a first row but there is no guarantee that running the same query again with the same data will produce the same first row. Tables in a relational database are not ordered so there is no specified *existing order* at all. You're making a bad assumption; the implementation may implicitly order the records by the PK on the disk but there's no guarantee of that and no guarantee that the next version will behave the same; furthermore, there's no guarantee that the database will return rows in disk-order, the database is free to order the rows in any way it wants to unless you have specified a specific order with an ORDER BY clause.

If you want an order then you should include an ORDER BY clause; you probably want something more like this:

```
a = A.where("col2 = :id OR col1 = :id", {:id => 3}).order(:id).first
```

And if you want to look at `col2` before `col1` then you should say so:

```
a =  A.where('col2 = :id', :id => 3).order(:id).first \
  || A.where('col1 = :id', :id => 3).order(:id).first
```

`col2 = :id OR col1 = :id` and `col1 = :id OR col2 = :id` are equivalent boolean expressions so the database is free to check `col2 = :id` before, after, or at the same time as `col1 = :id` and it is free to access the rows in any order it pleases.

Comment: You will still won't be able to guarantee that col2 = :id will be evaluated first. It's still possible col1 = :id could be evaluated first right?

Comment: This is especially true with Postgres as compared with MySQL

Comment: @daniel: I don't think there is any guarantee about the column order either, the database is free to rearrange the WHERE clause as it sees fit (as long as the the result is the same). If you want anything to happen in any particular order then you have to arrange it by hand.

Comment: +1, In my current solution is similar to what you have suggested (i.e. piping the results). I didn't think of the fact that I might be returning two rows. Should have been obvious. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you can't, use a case statement:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-EXPRESS-EVAL

> A CASE construct used in this fashion will defeat optimization attempts, so it should only be done when necessary